Rubin's rules Predicted values from mice imputed datasets and rms library
I am starting an analysis midway so my starting point is multiple imputed datasets created using the mice.
# Load libraries
library(rms)
library(mice)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123) # For reproducibility

# Number of observations
n <- 100

# outcome
y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.07)

# bmi
bmi <- runif(n, min = 16, max = 60)
bmi[sample(1:n, size = round(0.12 * n))] <- NA 
    # Introduce missing values

# tiktok_ban
tiktok_ban <- sample(1:90, size = n, replace = TRUE)
# tiktok_ban[sample(1:n, size = round(0.05 * n))] <- 0 
# Force some values to be 0

# sex
child_sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = n, replace = TRUE, 
                      prob = c(0.49, 0.51))
child_sex[sample(1:n, size = round(0.05 * n))] <- NA 
# Introduce missing values

# Combine into a data frame
df <- data.frame(y, bmi, tiktok_ban, child_sex)

# View first rows of the dataset
head(df)

################################################################################
    
imputed_df <- mice(df, print = FALSE, m = 20, seed = 24415, 
    method = "pmm", printFlag = FALSE)
    
imputed_df_l <- mice::complete(imputed_df, "long", include = FALSE)

I am able to fit the model on mice imputed datasets and obtain summary estimates and predicted values. I am using the using Predict function from the rms package.
    
d    <- imputed_df_l
dd   <- datadist(d);  options(datadist='dd')

Hmisc::describe(imputed_df_l$tiktok_ban)

k  <- attr(rcs(imputed_df_l$tiktok_ban, 6), 'parms')
k

h <- function(x) {
  z <- cbind(rcspline.eval(x, k),
             #sin=sin(2*pi*x/12), cos=cos(2*pi*x/12),
             jump=x >= 20)
  attr(z, 'nonlinear') <- 2 : ncol(z)
  z
}
        ################################################################################
m1 <- lapply(1:20, function(i){
f <- lrm(y ~ child_sex + bmi +
             gTrans(tiktok_ban, h),
             data= subset(imputed_df_l, .imp == i))
pred <- Predict(f, tiktok_ban)
return(pred)
})

My goal is to examine how the outcome changes over time. The predicted values from the 20 imputed datasets are stored as a list object.
m1[[1]], m1[[2]], .....m1[[20]]

However, I am unsure how to apply Rubin's Rules to these predicted values, as the Predict function does not provide standard errors.
Kindly advise on the best approach to pool these predicted value ? Appreciate your guidance.

Welcome to Cross Validated! The Predict() function by default includes 95% confidence intervals in the object that it returns, in the lower and upper columns of the returned data frame. With a model fit via maximum likelihood, as with lrm(), the 95% confidence intervals (in the linear predictor scale, for which Rubin's normality assumption holds the best) will be $\pm 1.96$ times the standard error around the point estimate in the yhat column. A few lines of code should provide an additional column with the standard errors.
